# Extracting information from a windows executable

Tags: c++, c

I've been given the task of writing a functional clone for an executable since we don't have the source code.

None of the .NET tools at my disposable recognise it and loading the thing into a text editor, I see the telltale:

```
MZ...This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

Further down I see:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
```

And further on still:

```
MultiByteToWideChar
```

Leading me to conclude it is a C/C++ executable. So far so good.

Without wasting days trying to find a disassembler, is there anything that could help me glean any further information from this type of executable? I already know about [Sysinternals Strings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx) application. I've also found something that can dump the assembly code (for all the good this does me!).

Comment: If you are looking for a magic bullet I have to disappoint you. The best you'll really get is IDA pro for reverse engineering and that is time consuming. The best way is probably write tests for the current exe, and then build your new exe to be compliant with the tests.

Comment: Have a look at excellent article [Peering Inside the Windows Portable Executable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms809762.aspx) by Matt Pietrek.

Comment: The old tool, PEiD was often useful. IDA Pro is unparalleled - quite useful for such a task. The (IDAPro) ability to turn binary code into a flowchart doesn't exactly suck...

Comment: @djgandy My hopes weren't high. They're happy with a functional clone but they're just nervous about any undocumented edge cases...

Comment: some apps have main functionalities located inside DLL's in such case you can use them directly and the app is just front end form calling functions from DLL's. Otherwise it is usually much faster to encode the App from scratch mirroring functionality then dive into disassembling and hoping that disassembled stuff will make some sense or even work as should.

Comment: Well, to be honest with you that task is herculean and your question a bit open-ended (not at last because we know nothing about the file in question). This doesn't look like a .NET binary, so it's likely a "native" Win32 program, presumably written in MSVC. You may want to have a look into Hopper for an affordable disassembler with decompiler. While IDA Pro with Hex-Rays will be even better, the price point is steep. Whoever tasked you has to _define_ what entails "functional clone". Typically a reverse engineer will always look at code areas of interest. In your case these may be vast ...